# undefined symbol: __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to compile C++ using clang's address sanitizer to output the sanitize results within a core dump, so I added:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=address
```

to have the compiler options:

```
/opt/llvm-3.8.0/bin/clang++ \
  --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-5.2.0 -fsanitize=address -DLINUX \
  -DLINUX64 -DTB_USE_RCU -DURCU_INLINE_SMALL_FUNCTIONS \
  -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DNDEBUG -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS \
  -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTB_USE_RCU -DTB_USE_RCU \
  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -m64 --gcc-toolchain=/opt/gcc-5.2.0 \
  -flto=full -std=gnu++14 -D_GLIBCXX_DEPRECATED= -pipe \
  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only \
  -pthread -march=core2 -mtune=corei7 -g -O3 -Qunused-arguments \
  -fnon-call-exceptions -fvisibility=hidden \
  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow \
  -Wpointer-arith -Wno-self-assign -Wno-unused-function \
  -Wno-gnu-empty-initializer -Wno-unused-parameter \
  -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-mismatched-tags \
  -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-parentheses-equality \
  -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-missing-field-initializers \
  -Wno-missing-braces -Werror=return-type \
  -Werror=overloaded-virtual -c MyClass.cpp -o MyClass.o
```

but I get the error:

```
undefined symbol: __asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return
```

What's the simplest way to resolve this?

Comment: You also need `LDFLAGS=-fsanitize=address`. The sanitizer flags need to be passed to the linker as well

Comment: @Justin this alone didn't solve it (I haven't tried the below answer yet)

Comment: @Justin This should be the answer.

Comment: @mezamorphic Did you make sure to _link_ with `-fsanitize=address`? Use of `-lasan` is not recommended by Asan developers.

Comment: @mezamorphic Please check my answer to [50621054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621054) and vote if it helps. We'll then be able to close as dup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting undefined symbol: \_\_asan\_memset when trying to use Clang address sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621054/getting-undefined-symbol-asan-memset-when-trying-to-use-clang-address-sanitiz)

Comment: I think it's not a dup: OP describes an issue when using `-fsanitize=address` in combination with `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden`.
Nevertheless, at runtime the `LD_PRELOAD=libclang_rt.asan.so` is a valid work-around

Comment: Seems to be CMake script specific. Locally reproducing the issue, I can only see this when indeed `-fsanitize=address` is missing from the linker lines (I still see OPs issue in a larger project, even though my verbose make output includes this during link)